# MCPC+ 1.6.4 Console Spam

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm running a modded minecraft server with MCPC+, the console is being spammed with

> 12.12 13:15:30 [Server] INFO long2
>
> 12.12 13:15:29 [Server] INFO long2
>
> 12.12 13:15:29 [Server] INFO long2
>
> 12.12 13:15:29 [Server] INFO long2
>
> 12.12 13:15:28 [Server] INFO long2
>
> 12.12 13:15:28 [Server] INFO long2
>
> 12.12 13:15:27 [Server] INFO long2
>
> 12.12 13:15:27 [Server] INFO long2
>
> 12.12 13:15:27 [Server] INFO long2
>
> 12.12 13:15:26 [Server] INFO long2
>
> 12.12 13:15:26 [Server] INFO long2
>
> 12.12 13:15:25 [Server] INFO long2
>
> 12.12 13:15:25 [Server] INFO long2
>
> 12.12 13:15:25 [Server] INFO long2
>
> 12.12 13:15:24 [Server] INFO 0.64141744 0.5

every few seconds, Its using the server plugins TekkitCustomizer, Vault, WorldEdit, Modifyworld, PermissionsEx, Herochat, Prism, Reporter, PluginManager, CommandBook, WorldGuard, WorldBorder, and a Forge version of DynMap.

EDIT: it has nothing to do with the plugins, I disabled all of them and it continued.

As for mods, its using the horizon (1.06) Feed-The-Beast modpack.

Anyone have a clue what could be causing this?

Comment: one of the mods is doing a bunch of `System.out.println("long"+somevar);`

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem on my ftb server.
Using a console filter plugin will do the work:
http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/consolefilter/